# Html.ActionLink and RedirectToAction incorrect within embedded route handler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

To allow common resources and views to be shared across multiple web projects, I have assembled a DLL that contains these layouts, etcetera.  To achieve this, I have an route handler that looks for any Uri that begins with `Embedded/` and goes to a custom handler to process.  This all works nicely, and is registered thusly:

```
    RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0,
            new Route("Embedded/{*file}",
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { }),
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { }),
                new EmbeddedResourceRouteHandler()));
```

Where it breaks, however, is when I use `ActionLink` or `RedirectToAction`.  Debugging the latter, it appears my `Embedded/` route is being selected as the route to use, and so instead of getting a uri of `{controller}/{action}`, I end up with `Embedded?controller={controller}&action={action}`.

The line is:

```
ActionResult result = RedirectToAction("Expired", "Operations");
```

And as you can see in the image below, this is what the route table looks like.  Note that my embedded one is first:

[image]

And the resultant Uri is:

[image]

I have tried adding the embedded route handler as the *last* route handler, but then it *never* gets called.  Would appreciate some guidance on this, and if you need more information, please let me know!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea might be applying a constraint to other routes (including the default) and placing the Embedded in the very end of the route table. Example of a constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { controller = "^(?!Embedded).+"}
);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks very much - I was about to tear my hair out.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, frankly speaking I do not think this is the best solution, since it requires a constraint for every route. There should be a way to tune up the Embedded route only, I just cannot think of one. But if this solution works for you - great.

Comment: true - at the moment, the default route is the only one.  In the event more routes are added I may well obfuscate the process out to a custom `MapRoute` function that automatically provides the constraint and takes the onus off the developer to do so.